# Unable to build project due to EPERM error

Tags: next.js13

esportfolio@0.1.0 build

> next build

- info Loaded env from C:\Users\Abdul Mohiz\Desktop\My-Portfolio.env
- info Linting and checking validity of types
  uncaughtException [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Abdul Mohiz\Desktop\My-Portfolio.next\trace'] {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\Users\Abdul Mohiz\Desktop\My-Portfolio\.next\trace'
  }
- info Creating an optimized production build .

While building, I'm getting this error. can someone please tell me what is it?
I'm using next js 13.

Comment: hello abdul welcome to stack overflow! Are you trying to create a production build?

Comment: Yeah, I was creating production build. The error was solved by deleting .next directory and then reinstalling it by using npm i.